# Is multiple Elasticsearch nodes on a single server faster?

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch index is very small (about 200,000 items). But I have a very large query volume (5000-10000 queries/second).

I have a dedicated server with 48GB RAM and a powerful CPU (20 cores). When I run a single ES node on this server, it consumes very little memory and RAM. But with high query volume, ES will time out.

My question are:

Is this better for me to create 10 nodes on the same server to fully utilize the server's RAM and CPU?

Will it be the same as creating 10 servers, each with 5 GB RAM and 2 cores?

(I read somewhere that normally, I should have one node per server, but it's a waste if we can't utilize our powerful server).

Comment: What is the max memory you've allocated to your node? An example of a query you are performing as well would be useful. Mapping etc.

Comment: Also this article might help you http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_improving_performance.html

Comment: Hi Nate, I allocate 2 GB per node. The nodes never use up memories anyway.